# Is a public setter necessary for private static variable?

Tags: java

```
/* Atleast is it needed in this case?*/
 public class Service
{       
         private static List<String> subscribedFields;
    private static List<String> unsubscribedFields;
         //---------------------------------  
         // is this necessary?
         //---------------------------------
    public static void setFields(List<String> subscribedFields, List<String> unsubscribedFields)
    {
        Service.subscribedFields = subscribedFields;
        Service.unsubscribedFields = unsubscribedFields;
    }
    public static List<String> getSubscribedFields()
    {
        return subscribedFields;
    }
    public static List<String> getUnsubscribedFields()
    {
        return unsubscribedFields;
    }
}
// some other class
public class User{
     // Is this not enough to change the lists? Isn't the setter redundant? 
     Change(Service.getSubscribedFields());
     Change(Service.getUnsubscribedFields());

}
```

Comment: How do the field values get initialised? And why must they be static?

Comment: I dont need an instance of the Service as it derives from another AbstractService class. So I am going with static fields, so that later developers dont try to instantiate an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a public setter is not always needed for a private variable. The idea of providing public setters (and getters, for that matter) is based on - what external entities such as classes need access to the insides of the particular piece of code you are writing. Getters and setters provide that public interface for that to happen. However, you don't necessarily NEED to provide a public getter or setter to every private variable you create as that private variable may only exist for internal, private use to the class.

You'll have to decide if you specifically need to give access to your private variables based on the particular needs of your code.

**Update Based on ada's Question in Comments**

You could give the user access to your lists directly (yes - they can use the getter and then edit the list). This may work if you trust the users of your code. However, for various reasons, you may not want to give them direct access to your list like that (especially because it gives them free reign to do what they want to do, it can create problems if you have threading within your application, etc). In that case, you should provide interfaces into the underlying list. For example, in your class, instead of providing a getSubscribedFields(), you may want to provide methods like:

```
// Pseudocode
public String getSubscribedField(int i) {
  return subscribedFields.Get(i);
}

public String addSubscribedField(String field) {
  subscribedFields.Add(field);
}
```

Hopefully that helps clarify things a bit for you.

Comment: I need some user code to change the fields lists. So I need access to the private fields outside. If user is able to change the list by just calling getter and altering the list returned, isn't the setter redundant?

Answer (score 1):

The more popular choice in this case is to use a Singleton which you initialize once with the fields.  However, not even Singleton is really a good idea, but to do otherwise requires that we know a bit more about what you're trying to do.  In most cases you can get around using static instances by making it a member of a class with a long lifetime.  For example, if these fields were related to database fields, you'd associate it with a table class which holds information pertaining to a database table for instance.

Really it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am interested to know if it is a bad programming practise to not change the private variable by using an explicit setter.

Comment: Ah, you mean not having a method explicitly called `setSubscribedFields` and `setUnsubscribedFields`?  Well I figure it requires so little effort, I see no reason why you would do otherwise.

Comment: Because User's Change has access to the List object of Service, it can add elements to it right? So the private list of Service also gets this new element. User can add elements to Services private fields without calling the existing setFields() at all.

Comment: True, but there are some frameworks like hibernate which explicitly look for methods with specific names like "setSubscribedFields" and if it doesn't find it, it can't assign anything.  Perhaps hibernate isn't the best example, but my point is that it's better to follow the guidelines.  Besides, I think eclipse will even generate the setters and getters for you, so it's even trivial to do.

Answer (score 1):

No you shouldn't. And even more you should avoid static state.

Comment: It is not exactly state. The subscribeFields and unsubscribeFields are more like metadata. There is no data really that i have to store because everything has to be maintained on the fly in a blotter based on some messages received from external code or server.

Comment: @ada in this case make them immutable or unmodifiable. But it would be better, if you will create only one instance of Service without static variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your class seems to be very prone to thread safety problems. I also question the relevance of your need to put your List as static variables.

Another thing, your setter isn't in line with JavaBeans setters & getters standards, you might have problem if you want to integrate with some common frameworks.

I suggest you a variation of your class. I refactored it in order to keep the responsibility of the class is to hold the subscriptions.

If you use a dependency injection framework like Spring or Guice, you could simply make a class like this one, and inject it to the classes that need this object.

```
    public class SubscriptionServiceUsingDependencyInjection {

    private final Set<String> subscribedFields = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<String>();

    public boolean isSubscribed(String field_) {
        return subscribedFields.contains(field_);
    }
    public void subscribe(String field_) {
        subscribedFields.add(field_);
    }
}
```

Otherwise If you really need a Singleton, you may use an enum to achieve the same goal :

```
    public enum SubscriptionServiceUsingASingleton {
    INSTANCE;
    private final Set<String> subscribedFields = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<String>();

    public boolean isSubscribed(String field) {
        return subscribedFields.contains(field);
    }
    public void subscribe(String field) {
        subscribedFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

The CopyOnWriteArraySet will prevent concurrency problem if you are running this in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Now I understood the major problem, the one with thread safety, thanks to Jascav, Stas and Tony and others. Thanks a lot people. You gave me several alternatives. :) Tony thanks for the comments on javabeans standards.